# Any idea why I am getting this error trying to install Toad for MySQL?

Tags: installation, mysql, toad

I am trying to install toad for mysql and i am getting this error during installation.  Any suggestion[image]

Comment: Do you have drive H:? Are you installing from an external media or just a file on your regular drive? Are there external USB memories/disks connected?

Comment: I do have a drive h . . i am simply installing from the internet

Comment: _When_ during installation does it happen? Do you choose to install it on drive H:? The more info you give directly, the more time people can spend on figuring out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First time i see this error message , but from a little google you can check [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327763)